# Help with RAID 10 Array that can't be found

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, raid, mdadm

I messed up. I just went through reinstalling and recovering an array yesterday. The array was working just fine. However, I was having a problem with an external drive wanting to be booted by the BIOS. I went into the BIOS and loaded the default settings.

Now my system doesn't see the RAID drive, and the command that pieced it together yesterday, sudo mdadm --assemble --scan is not finding the drive. sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde is not working either.

Here's the main crutch of my question: If I recreate the array (and not try to recreate the ext4 partition on the array) do I run any risk of losing data?

Edit:I'm considering running mdadm --create /dev/md0 -v --assume-clean --level=raid10 --raid-device=4 /dev/sd[bcde] and then if i can't mount the partition I plan on using something like testdisk to search for one. Any advice would be appreciated.

Edit 2: I haven't done anything yet. Here's more information:

Results of ls -la /dev/disk/by-uuid

> ```
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 15 11:57 40cec677-2f33-494b-998a-b4404203eda2  ../../sda1
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 15 11:57 4e4c4847-93ae-4a01-b4af-a8b7bfae5afc -> ../../sda5
> ```

Results of mdadm.conf

> ```
> # Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
> #
>
> # by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
> # containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
> # wildcards if desired.
> #DEVICE partitions containers
>
> # auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
> CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes
>
> # automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
> HOMEHOST <system>
>
> # instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
> MAILADDR root
>
> # definitions of existing MD arrays
> ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=07e0921a:529e8434:58ca9dea:8e950b2e name=plex$
>
> # This file was auto-generated on Thu, 13 Oct 2016 16:38:46 -0400
> # by mkconf $Id$
> ```

Please let me know if there's any other information I can provide to help.

Edit 3: running the command in edit 1, I received the following:

> ```
> root@plex:~# mdadm --create /dev/md0 -v --assume-clean --level=raid10 --raid-device=4 /dev/sd[bcde]
> mdadm: layout defaults to n2
> mdadm: layout defaults to n2
> mdadm: chunk size defaults to 512K
> mdadm: /dev/sdb appears to be part of a raid array:
>     level=raid0 devices=0 ctime=Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
> mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sdb but will be lost or
>        meaningless after creating array
> mdadm: /dev/sdc appears to be part of a raid array:
>     level=raid0 devices=0 ctime=Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
> mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sdc but will be lost or
>        meaningless after creating array
> mdadm: /dev/sdd appears to be part of a raid array:
>     level=raid0 devices=0 ctime=Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
> mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sdd but will be lost or
>        meaningless after creating array
> mdadm: /dev/sde appears to be part of a raid array:
>     level=raid0 devices=0 ctime=Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
> mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sde but will be lost or
>        meaningless after creating array
> mdadm: size set to 4883639296K
> Continue creating array?
> ```

I chose no and am awaiting advice. At least mdadm can see my raid array, even if it can't automatically assemble it.

Edit 4: Just more information:

> ```
> root@plex:~# mdadm --query /dev/sd[bcde]
> /dev/sdb: is not an md array
> /dev/sdb: device 0 in 0 device unknown raid0 array.  Use mdadm --examine for more detail.
> /dev/sdc: is not an md array
> /dev/sdc: device 0 in 0 device unknown raid0 array.  Use mdadm --examine for more detail.
> /dev/sdd: is not an md array
> /dev/sdd: device 0 in 0 device unknown raid0 array.  Use mdadm --examine for more detail.
> /dev/sde: is not an md array
> /dev/sde: device 0 in 0 device unknown raid0 array.  Use mdadm --examine for more detail.
> ```

And the more details:

> ```
> root@plex:~# mdadm --examine /dev/sd[bcde]
> /dev/sdb:
>    MBR Magic : aa55
> Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
> /dev/sdc:
>    MBR Magic : aa55
> Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
> /dev/sdd:
>    MBR Magic : aa55
> Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
> /dev/sde:
>    MBR Magic : aa55
> Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's what got it going.

Recreate the array. Ignore warning about losing data.

Use testdisk to search for and find partition.

Reboot

Mount and we're good. :)